# Current Modification Exception Android Iterators

Tags: java, android, iterator

I'm getting `CurrentModificationException` and I cannot figure out why. This is my code:

```
Iterator<Ficha> itFichas = puzzle.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> index = randomNum.iterator();
while(itFichas.hasNext() && index.hasNext()){
    PAleatorio.add(index.next(),itFichas.next());
}
```

I have previously defined `puzzle` as `ArrayList<Integer>`. And `randomNum`, `PAleatorio` as `ArrayList<Ficha>`.

Why am I getting the exception?

EDIT:

`ArrayList<Ficha> PAleatorio = finalList;`

where finalList is another list with several `Ficha`:

```
ArrayList<Ficha> finalList = new ArrayList<Ficha>();

finalList.add(new Ficha("1"));
finalList.add(new Ficha("2"));
finalList.add(new Ficha("3"));
finalList.add(new Ficha("4"));
```

Comment: can you show the declaration of **PAleatorio**

Comment: just post a bit more of context and the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: In all its probability, `puzzle` and `PAleatorio` refer to the same object.

Comment: @GopalRao I added it to the post.

Comment: now pls show the declaration of puzzle too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have previously defined puzzle as `ArrayList<Integer>`. And randomNum, PAleatorio as `ArrayList<Ficha>`."
You mean `puzzle` is `ArrayList<Ficha>` and `randomNum` `ArrayList<Integer>` right?
And i recreat the szenario with some testobjects. The only reason for a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` can be that `PAleatorio` and `puzzle` store the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to do it like this:

```
int counter = 0;
do{
    PAleatorio.add(index.get(counter),itFichas.get(counter));
   counter++;
}while(counter <= itFichas.size() && counter <= index.size());
```